# mysql table indexing on null timestamp

Tags: mysql, indexing, timestamp

I have a mysql table with a timestamp field.
Most of the queries on this table will be `where someIntegerIield=? and theTimestampField is null`.

Should I use the timestamp field as part of the index?
Or should I create and maintain another filed that will be set to 0 when the timestamp field is null and 1 otherwise ?

Other alternatives are also welcome.

Comment: I could be mistaken but as far as I know MySQL can **not** use an index for an `IS NULL` condition.

Comment: You could also be right. any idea where can this be verified ?

Comment: alternatively, can I use an index for `time between timestamp1 and timestamp2`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I think MySQL can use an index for that. Oracle (some older version) could not, if I remember well.

Comment: @ypercube: that seems right: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/98ae3/2 Maybe that changed with newer versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can use an index for "time between timestamp1 and timestamp2". Default index type in MySQL / InnoDB is BTREE, which works with comparisons too (<, >, between), as well as prefixes.
And yes, MySQL does use IS NULL/ IS NOT NULL in index conditions. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en//is-null-optimization.html for some table types (including InnoDB).

If you are on an earlier version of MySQL, you can always try "EXPLAIN": it will tell you if it uses an index or not (and which) for your query